# Lightning datatable displays empty field as 'undefined' instead of blank in LWC

Tags: javascript

I have an LWC in which I used datatable to display addresses. I have constructed address separately (as it is a combination of various fields) and provided it to datatable. Problem is, when a field is blank, the datatable displays `undefined` instead of blank. How can I display only the data that is filled? Please guide.

[image]

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
const columns = [
    // Other Columns
    { label: 'Address',initialWidth: 310, fieldName: 'Address_custom', type: 'text' },
];

@wire(getAddress, { contact_Id: '$recordId' }) wired(result) {
        this.refreshTable = result;
        if (result.data) {
            let preparedAddresses = [];
            result.data.forEach(address => {
            let preparedAddress = {};
            // Other Fields
            preparedAddress.Address_custom = address.AddressID.Building_Name__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.Street_Address__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.Street_Address_1__c+'\nPO Box: '+address.AddressID.PO_Box_Number__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.City__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.Postal_Code__c;
            preparedAddresses.push(preparedAddress);
            });
            this.addresses = preparedAddresses;
        }
        if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below line you have concatenated strings without checking for null/blank, so whenever it is not defined, the string is converted as undefined while concatenating.

```
preparedAddress.Address_custom = address.AddressID.Building_Name__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.Street_Address__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.Street_Address_1__c+'\nPO Box: '+address.AddressID.PO_Box_Number__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.City__c+'\n'+address.AddressID.Postal_Code__c;
```

So add a null check before adding like this.

```
preparedAddress.Address_custom = '';
if(address.AddressID.Building_Name__c){
    preparedAddress.Address_custom += address.AddressID.Building_Name__c+'\n';
}
if(address.AddressID.Street_Address__c){
    preparedAddress.Address_custom += address.AddressID.Street_Address__c
}
//.. so on
```

Also, you can use a ternary operator like this.

```
abc = (this.a ? this.a : '') + (this.b ? this.b : '') + (this.c ? this.c : '');
```